# Quantum states transform like vectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, quantum-states

One may define vectors as tuples satisfying the vector transformation law, or as elements of a vector space.  On the latter, the superposition of two quantum states is another state, and the product of two states is non-state scalar.  The vacuum state $|\psi\rangle=0$ exists and, for a scalar $a$ and a state $|\psi\rangle$, the product $a|\psi\rangle$ is still a state vector.  Briefly, the axioms of a vector space are satisfied.  **My question regards the idea that state vectors *transform* like vectors.**

Since states may not be position states, or states with any sort of directionality, I am not sure how to apply the concept of coordiante transformation in an abstract vector space.  For instance, if I say,

> "Let $\hat R(\hat n,\phi)$ be a rotation operator and $|\psi\rangle=|a\rangle+|b\rangle$ so that $\hat R|\psi\rangle=\hat R|a\rangle+\hat R|b\rangle$ obviously preserves the `angle' between $a$ and $b$, meaning that $\hat R|a\rangle$ and $\hat R|b\rangle$ are still orthogonal,"

then I am not satisfied that I have shown the proper vector transformation.  Since the states themselves are the spanning basis of the state space, I am not quite getting the gist of what a coordinate transformation would be such that I could make a demonstration like the one below copied from Wolfram.  What is the general proof that quantum states transform like vectors even when they are not states directly related to $\mathbb{R}^3$ coordinates?  Following the form below, if I start with

$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_k a_k|\psi_k\rangle\quad\implies\quad\psi_i=a_{ik}\psi_k$$

then how should I proceed?  Namely, what are my $x_i$ and $x_j$ in the vector space of quantum states?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you are confusing several things here. Vectors are defined by the [axioms of the vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

When you talk about vectors transforming in a certain way, I think you are talking about the vectors in the tangent space of some differentiable manifold. This an additional concept. Not all vectors must have a tangent space in which they 'live'. For example, differential one-forms (e.g. $dx,\,dy,\,dz$) are vectors, dual to vectors you are more used to, and they certainly do not transform in the way you describe. By definition, one-forms will do the opposite. A more life-like example is magnetic field. It is an axial vector, and as a result it transforms under reflection in a rather curious way.

As far as state-vectors transforming in a certain way. I feel like the natural way to go here is [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem)

Comment: When I talk about vectors transforming in certain way, I mean that an N-dimensional state space is spanned by $\hat e_1,\hat e_2,...\hat e_N$ in the same way that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is spanned by $\hat x,\hat y, \hat z$.  You can do coordinate transformations on the linearly independent spanning basis of an N-dimensional state space exactly as if it were $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I ended up figuring out my question.  I just need to write $x_i$ and $x_j$ in terms of the $\hat e_n$ instead of the $\mathbb{R}^3$ basis.

Comment: Usually people don't think of state spaces as geometric spaces, but they are that.  It's just weird to think of spin-up, for example, serving the same purpose in state space as $\hat x$ does in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @hodopsmith state spaces can be infinite dimensional, in which case, I think your approach to spanning them may need to be more subtle. In reply to "usually people don't think of state spaces as geometric spaces"... perhaps it is a blank in my education but I don't know this term. I get the meaning, I think, but I don't think I know the definition. Topological spaces, metric spaces, manifolds, differentiable manifolds, vector spaces, all make sense. What is a geometric space?

Comment: @hodopsmith, I am pretty sure that to talk about rotations in the way you talk about them you need some sort of a manifold, i.e. you need a point -set with a defined topology and then a differentiable map that maps this topological space into itself (which then can be rotation under some restrictions). Now each point on that manifold could have a tangent space, and could therefore be the state space you describe, but each tangent space will be completely different, unless you have some connection between them. What I am getting at is that having $N$ basis vectors does not mean you are in R^N

Comment: You need a lot more structure which seems unnecessary for state vectors in a Hilbert space.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be more subtle because you can show the vector transformation with a rotation and then say it it holds under all transformations.  A rotation specifies some $\hat e_k$ as the rotation axis and infinite dimensions doesn't affect it at all.   English is the official language of science and mathematics because it is convenient for everyone to use the same dictionary for finding the definitions of words.  If you understand that a geometric space is a "space" with a "geometric" character, then you have perfectly understood me.  Thanks for your nice comment!

Comment: Perhaps you did not see where I said, "You can treat it as $\mathbb{R}^n$."  I think you are wrong your comment "you need a lot more structure" so maybe you could clarify?  As it is, I don't see why I would "need some sort of point-set topology" when I inherent the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which I have already cited in my comment preceding your comment.  Can you please explain so I can better understand?

Comment: @hodopsmith, an old post, but might as well comment now rather than never. Lets imagine your quantum state describes a multi-electron cloud that is in motion. The vectors to consider are now spin, and current density. You can probably generalize it to a four-current defined at each point in space. So at each point in space you have another vector space in which the four-current lives. In addition to this the number of electrons in each point is variable, so now there is some sort of Fock space attached to it. When you do your rotation, you somehow need to describe how Fock space does ...

Comment: not rotate, but current does. Better still it might be better to work with four-current, but then rotation is happening in a specific slice of a four-space, so that will need a proper description. You mentioned rotations - those will be easier. What about reflections? Velocity is a polar vector, whilst spin is an axial vector, both contribute to current density. So now representation of your reflection will need to be appropriate for axial vectors, polar vectors, and Fock-space etc. So a lot of structure.

Comment: And this is before we note that rotations here will move the spatial distribution of electron density. So you will also need an appropriate operator to act upon your state that describes the density of the electrons. It may not be rotation in the normal sense, but it will be a unitary transformation.

Answer (score 1):

States live in a Hilbert space which is typically infinite-dimensional where standard coordinate transformations don't apply. However,  unitary representations of the rotational group on elements of the Hilbert space can be applied. These representations follow the following rules ($R$ -- $R_1$ and $R_2$ too -- is a rotation from the rotation group SO(3)):

$$U(R) U(R)^\dagger =1 \quad\text{and}\quad U(R_1)U(R_2) = U(R_1 R_2)$$

Trivially one has also (no rotation)  :  $$U(1) = 1$$

However, it depends strongly on the state what effect they might have. If for instance it acts on a momentum state $|\mathbf{p} \rangle$ one gets:

$$U(R)|\mathbf{p} \rangle = |\mathbf{ R p} \rangle$$

This means that if

$$\hat{p}_z |\mathbf{p} \rangle  = p_z  |\mathbf{p} \rangle$$

then the rotated state will an eigenvector to a different eigenvalue:

$$\hat{p}_z |R\mathbf{p} \rangle  = Rp_z  |R\mathbf{p} \rangle$$

Of course the action of the rotation $R$ on $p_z$ is one we are used to in classical physics.

A Hilbert space is a vector space which moreover has a scalar product and is complete. So states indeed live in a vector space, but not the one we used to from classical physics. In order to explain what the vector space means I give a simple example:

One can decompose a member $f$  -- we assume for this very simple example $f$ as periodic with a period of $2\pi$ -- of the Hilbert space (typically a function $\in\, L_2$, but other mathematical spaces are possible (with differently defined scalar product)) in a Fourier series:

$$f(\phi) = \sum_{n=0,\ldots,\infty} a_n E_n \equiv  \sum_{n=0,\ldots,\infty} a_n e^{in \phi}$$

Then the $e^{in \phi}$ are the base vectors $E_n$ and the $(a_n)$ are the components of the Hilbert space vector $f$. (I denoted the base vectors with a capital $E$ in order to avoid confusion with the $e$ from the exponential function).
The components can, as it is well known, computed by projecting the  vector $f$ on the different base vectors by means of the scalar product:

$$a_n = <f, E_n> = < f, e^{in\phi}>$$

which in a Hilbert space is an integral:

$$ <f,g> = \int f(\phi) \overline{g(\phi)} d\phi$$

Therefore:

$$ a_n = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi) e^{-in\phi} d\phi$$